# WebView When loading Not fully displayed

Tags: react-native

http://u9801853.viewer.maka.im/k/TLTOBXVU,
This URL is not fully displayed in the React Native webview. It can be displayed when you slide up to the third page. The information page of the first page is not displayed. It is normal when loading in the Android native WebView.

Comment: The second page is originally blank.

Comment: Did you use WebView react native component or any other plugin ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: can you share your related code for us to help you out ?

Answer (score 0):

I know what the problem is, if startInLoadingState={true} is set, it will be interrupted.
in WebView component, layout is broken for some web pages, so, delete startInLoadingState={true} is ok